# Create different instances of class

Tags: javascript

Currently I am declaring JS classes like in this next example:

```
function X(a) {
    this.x = a;
    X.prototype.do = function () {
        console.log(x);
    }
}
```

I want to remove the 'this' keyword, so now my classes looks like in this example:

```
function X(a) {
    var x = a;
    X.prototype.do = function () {
        console.log(x);
    }
}
```

This works great when I have one instance of X class. When I try to create more than one instance I see the next problem:

```
var x1 = new X(1); 
x1.do();    // prints 1
var x2 = new X(2);
x2.do();    // prints 2
x1.do();    // prints 2 instead of 1
```

That problem prevents me from creating multiple instances of the same class.
Does anyone know why this problem occur and how to avoid it?

Comment: In the first example, `x` is not declared. And never alter the prototype inside the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are redefining the ***`prototype`*** implementation of the method, which means you're redefining it for every instance of the class. And since the method returns a closed over value, it returns the same for every instance of the class.

Write it either as:

```
function X(a) {
    this.x = a;
}

X.prototype.do = function () {
    console.log(this.x);
}
```

or:

```
function X(a) {
    this.do = function () {
        console.log(a);
    };
}
```

Not a weird mix of both.

Comment: Great! The second option is what I looked for. I will accept the answer in 8 minutes :)

Comment: Note that this is not typically a great idea to redefine methods on each object in the constructor. You *should* be using the first method. Not sure why you "want to get rid of `this`" so badly...

Comment: I need to make the variables in this class private. Do you have any suggestion how to make that without redefining methods?

Comment: My stance on the issue is that "private" properties are overrated. If you want to signal "don't touch this", establish a naming convention like `_x`. No need to bend over backwards for something like this which is purely a programmer convention issue anyway.

Comment: I will consider that. Thanks anyway for the fast and helpful answer!